# More GPIO pins: use expansion boards, or 2 raspberry pi?

Tags: android-things

I'm planning to start a project using a RPi3 and Android Things. I need 50 GPIO pins  (20 inputs, 30 outputs), so I have 2 options: use an expansion board, or use 2 RPis. So I have a question for each option:

- If I use an expansion board: will be possible to use it with Android Things?
- If I use 2 RPis: what's the best way to communicate between them? (for example: a signal received in a GPIO in RPi A, may trigger an output in RPi B)

EDIT: Here I link a post that describes 3 ways to extend RPi's GPIO ports -> https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=86738#p611850 It may be useful

EDIT 2: I will use 2 MCP23017 (16 port expander). So I will get 32 pins using only the 2 I2C pins. More info: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf

Comment: Output pins are easily multi-plexable.  Input pins are more tricky to multiplex but it's do-able

Comment: @Seb if you elaborate a bit more, that could be a very good answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @Seb I agree with shalafi. Please, can you give us more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider the [PCF8574](http://www.nxp.com/products/interfaces/ic-bus-portfolio/ic-general-purpose-i-o/remote-8-bit-i-o-expander-for-icbus-with-interrupt:PCF8574_74A), which is I2C an 8 bit port expander. You can have up to 8 of them on a single I2C bus, giving you up to 64 GPIO pins.

Here is a driver for the PCF8574 for Android Things:

https://github.com/davemckelvie/things-drivers

Comment: Thanks. I think using an I2C port expander is the way to go. Also, thanks for the drivers :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Android Things but with some electronic work you will be able to achieve your results.

This 4 line decoder will only use 4 gpio pins to control 16 outputs.

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT154.pdf

The reverse process is also possible. You may use a 16 line "demultiplexer" to encode 16 bits of logic information in on 4 GPIO inputs of your Raspberry

http://www.ti.com/product/CD54HC4514

(the components I selected are the first one I stumbled across. They may not be the best products for your specific application.  I used the 74HC238 before on a project and it worked like a charm)

Comment: Thank you. I've read more about using a multiplexor. It works, but the only problem is that only one pin can be activated at a time.